# How do I group attrubutes while converting dataframe to xml in python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I am trying to convert my dataframe to xml in python.

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
LoaderTXNID Description ANUMS   Value Date  Fund
67805499    CA67805499  44554   1/27/2023       NC1_AR
67805499    CA67805499  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805499    CA67805499  11504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  16704   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  88504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  11504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  11504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  11504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  11504   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  33002   1/27/2023   NC1_AR
```

**Requirement:**

I want to convert it to xml resulting in something like below: (i.e Suppose for Description CA67805499 there are 3 ANUMS (44554, 33002 and 11504). So I want them under entries tag

```
Request
xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Transactions>
    <Transaction>
        <Description>CA67805499</Description>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <Anum>44554</Anum>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Anum>33002</Anum>
            </Entry>
                        <Entry>
                <Anum>11504</Anum>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <Description>CA67805501</Description>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <Anum>16704</Anum>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Anum>33002</Anum>
            </Entry>
                        <Entry>
                <Anum>88504</Anum>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </Transaction>
</Transactions>undefined</Request>
```

I wrote the following code to achieve the same:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Sddl\\Desktop\\twoigma.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')

with open('outputf.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(df.to_xml(index=False,row_name='Entry',root_name='Transaction',elem_cols={'ANUMS'},attr_cols={'Description'},pretty_print=True,parser='lxml'))
```

But I get result like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Transaction>

    

        <Entry Description="CA67805499">
            <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Description="CA67805499">
            <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Description="CA67805499">
            <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Description="CA67805501">
            <ANUMS>16704</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Description="CA67805501">
            <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Description="CA67805501">
            <ANUMS>88504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>

</Transaction>
```

How do I group by records in xml?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't see how you can do it with `to_xml()` because of how your expected xml is nested. It can be done "manually", if you can use lxml.

Comment: @JackFleeting, `to_xml` supports XSLT 1.0 with `stylesheet` argument. So, a user can modify the raw flat XML output to *any* design, nested or not, she needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your needed output is a specialized, grouped XML, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language to transform XML files and sibling to XPath.

Both pandas `read_xml` and `to_xml` supports XSLT 1.0 using the `lxml` parser for reading from and writing to complex XML files. Specifically, run the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for grouping `<ANUMS>` by `<Description>` nodes with a new `<Request>` root *after* generating a flat XML with `to_xml`:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl or in a Python string where XSLT is a special XML type)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="desc-key" match="Entry" use="Description" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/Transaction">
   <Request
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Entry[count(. | key('desc-key', Description)[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="Description" />
          <Transaction>
              <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>
                <Entries>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('desc-key', Description)">
                  <Entry>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="ANUMS" />
                    </Entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </Entries>
            </Transaction>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:copy>
    </Request>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcCf4x)</kbd>

**Python**

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''LoaderTXNID Description ANUMS   "Value Date"  Fund
67805499    CA67805499  44554   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805499    CA67805499  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805499    CA67805499  11504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  16704   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805501    CA67805501  88504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  11504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  11504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805503    CA67805503  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  11504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  11504   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR
67805505    CA67805505  33002   "1/27/2023"   NC1_AR'''

with StringIO(txt) as f:
    annum_df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\\s+")

annum_df.to_xml(
    "outputf.xml",                          # OUTPUT XML
    index = False,
    row_name = 'Entry',
    root_name = 'Transaction',
    elem_cols = ['ANUMS', 'Description'],
    stylesheet = "style.xsl",               # EXTERNAL XSLT
    parser='lxml'
)
```

**Output XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Description>CA67805499</Description>
      <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>44554</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
      </Entries>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Description>CA67805501</Description>
      <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>16704</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>88504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
      </Entries>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Description>CA67805503</Description>
      <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
      </Entries>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Description>CA67805505</Description>
      <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>11504</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
          <ANUMS>33002</ANUMS>
        </Entry>
      </Entries>
    </Transaction>
  </Transaction>
</Request>
```